# start again for loop after return in python

Tags: python, for-loop

For loop stops after return.
How to make it loop again? 
n = len(series)
I need to return n separated lists with one integer in.

```
def _repeats(self, exercises, series):
    repeats = []
    for x in range(len(series)):
        repeats.append([])
    series_counter = 1
    for ex in exercises:
        n2 = 1
        print(series[series_counter - 1])
        print(type(series[series_counter - 1]))
        for serie in range(0, int(series[series_counter - 1])):
            x = int(input(
            "Number of repeats in {} serie {} : ".format(ex, n2)
                         ))
            repeats[n2 - 1].append(x)
            n2 += 1
            return repeats[n2 - 2]
        series_counter += 1
```

Comment: `return` ends a function. If you need to return multiple values, perhaps you want to build a list first and return *that* at the end?

Comment: I build a list of lists in lines 3,4 I want to return each list one after another, maybe should I use generator?

Comment: A generator would also work yes. But you can also put lists in another list.

Comment: https://github.com/kopc718/SUPER-NOWE-REPO/blob/master/new_training_notes.py < there is full code available, I know that is not the best you have ever seen but i just started to learn few weeks ago

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not really sure if i know what u mean, or how to do that works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to study Python's Control Flow topic. Including break and continue.
Also, read about generators and yield command.

Best of luck.